# Security group sg-0da667222da8a6eb2 does not appear to belong to the same VPC as the input subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

As part of the CI/CD Jenkins pipeline, I am deploying a springboot application to AWS EC2/Fargate using cloudformation from an image available at dockerhub. I have my access key, the secret, region, and subnet defined as secrets that are passed at runtime. The cloudformation deployment is failing with status CREATE_FAILED and the following error:

```
Invalid request provided: CreateService error: Security group
sg-0da667222da8a6eb2 does not appear to belong to the same VPC as the
input subnets. (Service: Ecs, Status Code: 400, Request ID:
503ce486-c3db-4d35-bb92-5f4770662c05, Extended Request ID: null)
```

Here is my cloudformation yaml file content:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
  SubnetID:
    Type: String
  ServiceName:
    Type: String
  ServiceVersion:
    Type: String
  DockerHubUsername:
    Type: String
Resources:
  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: deployment-example-cluster
  ServiceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: ServiceSecurityGroup
      GroupDescription: Security group for service
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 8080
          ToPort: 8080
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: !Sub ${ServiceName}-task
      Cpu: 256
      Memory: 512
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Sub ${ServiceName}-container
          Image: !Sub ${DockerHubUsername}/${ServiceName}:${ServiceVersion}
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 8080
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - EC2
        - FARGATE
  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Sub ${ServiceName}-service
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          Subnets:
            - !Ref SubnetID
          SecurityGroups:
            - !GetAtt ServiceSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

Here is screenshot of cloudformation stack building process:

[image]

Surprisingly, sg-0da667222da8a6eb2 is not one of my security groups. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: does any `serverless.yml` file there ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan There is no serverless.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a custom VPC and not the default VPC in my setup. When cloudformation kicks in, it looks to build the resources in the default VPC in the absence of the information provided. In my case when I pass the custom VPC from my Jenkins as an environment variable, the stack comes up as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ServiceSecurityGroup`, as it is defined, it is created in a **default VPC**. However, your `SubnetID` probably belongs to a **custom VPC**. Therefore, you have to provide [VpcId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#cfn-ec2-securitygroup-vpcid) for your `ServiceSecurityGroup`:

```
Parameters:

  VpcId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id

  # others not shown

Resources:

  # only relevant part shown

  ServiceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: ServiceSecurityGroup
      GroupDescription: Security group for service
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 8080
          ToPort: 8080
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId   

  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Sub ${ServiceName}-service
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          Subnets:
            - !Ref SubnetID
          SecurityGroups:
            - !GetAtt ServiceSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

Comment: I did add vpcId to the ServiceSecurityGroup as you suggested, but I still see the same issue. I have updated the details with the image from cloudformation stack. Not sure if that gives any further clues.

Comment: @rslj Go to VPC console, check which VPC is your `SubnetID` that you are using coming from. Your Security Group must be from same VPC. The groups are VPC specific.

Comment: believe it or not, I am working on your suggestion as I write. I will keep you posted once I get through this :-)